# MySQL Rails migration error: "Error on rename of schema_migration (errno: -1)"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm a PHP dev and I'm new to Rails but have been getting on pretty well, everything seems pretty straightforward. However, up until this morning I have been using SQLite and decided to move what I'm building to MySQL. rake db:create works perfectly, but when I attempt to rake db:migrate I get the following error:

> rake aborted! 
>   Mysql::Error: Error on
>   rename of
>   './test_development/schema_migrations'
>   to './test_development/#sql2-c7b-c'
>   (errno: -1): CREATE UNIQUE INDEX
>   `unique_schema_migrations` ON
>   `schema_migrations` (`version`)

Thinking that it might be an error in my migration scripts, I created a clean rails project with the simplest of tables and get the same error. So, I reinstalled MySQL and the mysql gem to ensure it wasn't something ill with either of those and I'm still having no luck. Here's the versions I'm running:

- Rails 2.3.4
- Ruby 1.8.6
- MySQL 5.1.40
- MySQL Gem 2.8.1

I have a feeling it could be InnoDB related, as I've had problems with that engine before on this box. But, if anyone can help me out I'd be extremely grateful as it's stopping me progressing.

Thanks,

Kieran

UPDATE: 
As requested by Phil here's the results of:

[SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS](http://kieranmasterton.com/SHOWENGINE.txt)

and

[SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb%'](http://kieranmasterton.com/SHOWVARS.txt)

Comment: As you say, this is probably an InnoDB issue. If you could post the result of running `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb%'` then someone may be able to spot what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks Phil, as requested I've updated my question with the results o both queries. Hope it can help someone solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got the [innodb_force_recovery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html) option set to 6. This was presumably changed from the default 0 to fix an earlier problem. InnoDB won't allow anything much other than `SELECT`, `CREATE TABLE` and `DROP TABLE` in this mode.

Try shutting down MySQL and then editing your my.cnf file. Set innodb_force_recovery to 0 (or remove the option) and then restart MySQL.

Comment: Argh! I did indeed add that at a previous occasion to fix another issue. Apologies, and thank you for your help!